# Passing switch parameter thru pipeline in PowerShell

Tags: function, powershell, csv

## Passing switch parameter thru pipeline in PowerShell

### Problem

I am trying to make a function that has a switch parameter, but also I want to able to pass all function parameters thru pipeline in a script, and I don't know ho to do that. Is it that even possible? I my case I load parameters from `.csv` file in witch values are string values.

### Exposition

To simplify my problem and to make it easier for others to use answers of this question, I am not going to use my code but an abstract version of my code. Let us call my function `New-Function` that has a `-StringParameter`, a `-IntParameter` and a `-SwitchParameter` parameters. And just to be clear in my `.csv` file all fields are named same as the `New-Function` parameters.

### Using the function

Normally I you can use the `New-Function` this way:

```
New-Function -StringParameter "value" -IntParameter 123 -SwitchParameter
```

But I also want to use the `New-Function` this way:

```
$Data = Import-Csv -Path "$PSScriptRoot\Data.csv" -Delimiter ';'
$Data | New-Function
```

### My attempts

I have tried to convert the string values in pipe line to `boolean` but it seems like the function's `-SwitchParameter` does not accept `boolean`(`$true`, `$false`) values, because it skipping the process block completely when I debug it.

```
$Data | ForEach-Object -Process {
    if ($_.SwitchParameter -eq "true") {
        $_.SwitchParameter = $true
    }
    else {
    $_.SwitchParameter = $false
    }
} | New-Function
```

### My temporary workaround

I have settled to use a string parameter instead of a switch parameter, so I can feed the `New-Function` with data thru pipeline from a .csv file with no problem.

```
function New-Function {
    param (
        [Parameter(Position = 0, Mandatory, ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName)]
        [string]
        $StringParameter,

        [Parameter(Position = 1, Mandatory, ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName)]
        [int]
        $IntParameter,

        [Parameter(Position = 2, ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName)]
        [string]
        $SwitchParameter = "false"
    )
#----------------------------------------------------------------------------
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can convert your string to a `Boolean` object while leaving your parameter as type `[switch]` in your function. The `Boolean` type will be coerced into `[switch]` during binding.

```
$Data | Foreach-Object {
    $_.SwitchParameter = [boolean]::Parse($_.SwitchParameter)
    $_
} | New-Function
```

Alternatively, you can update all of your objects first and then pipe to your function. It matters how your function handles the input objects.

```
$Data | Foreach-Object {
    $_.SwitchParameter = [boolean]::Parse($_.SwitchParameter)
}
$Data | New-Function
```

Part of the issue with your `Foreach-Object` attempt is that you never output the updated object `$_` before piping into your function.

Comment: O my God that is it! The `ForEach-Object` did not output the data to my function, and that was the problem. Now everything makes sense. Thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 1):

You have to convert values for switch parameter to boolean type.

It works to me:

```
function Out-Test
{
    param
    (
        [Parameter(ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName)]
        [String]
        $Label,
        [Parameter(ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName)]
        [Switch]
        $Show
    )
    process
    {
        $Color = if ($Show) { 'Yellow' } else { 'Gray' }
        Write-Host -ForegroundColor $Color $Label
    }
}

$row1 = '' | select Label, Show
$row1.Label = 'First'
$row1.Show = 'True'
$row2 = '' | select Label, Show
$row2.Label = 'Second'
$row1.Show = 'False'
$rows = $row1, $row2

$rows |% { $_.Show = [bool]$_.Show }
$rows | Out-Test
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, but I found that my method actually works, but I did not output the data from the `ForEach-Object` function to my function. I taught that the `ForEach-Object` function does that automatically.